# Regular Expression Issue while retrieving from database table

Tags: c#, regex

We have regular expression value `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$` in database table for nvarchar column . When we are retrieving expression from database table than we are getting expression value with special char like `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"`

This value is not evaluated . How I can ensure

- regular expression is valid expression
- How I can remove special char while getting expression values from database table.

This is the code:

```
public static bool IsMatch(string target, string pattern, RegexOptions options) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(target)) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
    } if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern)) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("pattern");
    }
    return Regex.IsMatch(target, pattern, options);
}
```

Comment: Don't insert the expression with the special character in the first place?

Comment: What is your regex supposed to be?  ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]$ ? Why don't you put that in the database then?

Comment: did you  try this:  `return Regex.IsMatch(target, Regex.Escape(pattern), options);`.   `Regex.Escape` will escape the special char, such as `* + ? ()`

Comment: I will check and let you know asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check if the regular expression is a valid regular expression, use [ArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
try
{
    var rxnew = new Regex(@"[z-a]");
}
catch (ArgumentException ae)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ae.Message);
    // Shows "parsing "[z-a]" - [x-y] range in reverse order."
}
```

You can unescape the `"` symbol by runing this S&R:

```
var str = "@\\\"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]$"; // Input: @\"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]$
var fixed_str = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<!\\\\)\\\\\"","\""); // Output: @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]$
```

Comment: The question has been modified, perhaps, the 2nd part of the answer is not relevant, is it?

Comment: I will check and let you know asap

Comment: stribizhev: In database we expression value @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" and while getting in code than expression value coming as "@\"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\""    . I am using RegexUtility.IsMatch(sourcestring, Regex.Replace("@\"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\""  , "(?<!\\\\)\\\\\"", "\""))    .Its not working.

Comment: You cannot use `IsMatch` with `Regex.Replace()` as 2nd argument. You should try `Regex.IsMatch(sourcestring, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*")`